# How to read array column as array not string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my `csv` file which has values like this:

`['Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p', 'Type: CARDINAL, Value: 10', 'Type: CARDINAL, Value: 10']`

The problem is when I load my data in a dataframe, I get a `string` instead of getting an array and I can't traverse through it.

I also have tried `json.loads()` but the problem is sometimes I have values like `["Type: TIME, Value: last night's"]` so I can't replace `single quotes (')` by `double quotes (")` and this stops json from parsing my string.

Any idea how to read my column as an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` for convert string representation of lists to `lists`:

```
import ast

a = "['Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p', 'Type: CARDINAL, Value: 10', 'Type: CARDINAL, Value: 10']"
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[a, a]}) 

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
print (df)
                                                 col
0  [Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p, Type: CARDINAL, V...
1  [Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p, Type: CARDINAL, V...

print (type(df.loc[0, 'col']))
<class 'list'>
```

EDIT:

If need to find all values which cannot be converted:

```
a = "['Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p', 'Type: CARDINAL, Value: 10', 'Type: CARDINAL, Value: 10']"
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[a, a,  'wrong "']}) 

def test(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except:
        return np.nan

df['new'] = df['col'].apply(test)
print (df)
                                                 col  \
0  ['Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p', 'Type: CARDINAL...   
1  ['Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p', 'Type: CARDINAL...   
2                                            wrong "   

                                                 new  
0  [Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p, Type: CARDINAL, V...  
1  [Type: CARDINAL, Value: 50p, Type: CARDINAL, V...  
2                                                NaN 

print (df[df['new'].isna()])

       col  new
2  wrong "  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Is there any way to convert this arrays to json objects?

Comment: @FarzinGhanbari - Yes, use `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(x)))`

Comment: I got this error:

```ValueError: malformed node or string: ['Type: CARDINAL, Value: more than 78']```

Comment: @FarzinGhanbari - It seems data related issue, how working `df['col'] = df['col'].str.strip("[]'").str.split("', '").apply(json.dumps)` ?

Comment: this worked but still I'm not getting what I want.
I'll work it out somehow.
Thank you for your time

Comment: @FarzinGhanbari - Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for explain what is problem? Or is necessary test values for failed?

Comment: You know, I couldn't understand your last comment.
Is there anyway we can contact?
like Instant messaging or even email?

Comment: @FarzinGhanbari - email is in my profile, only run code for email.

Comment: @FarzinGhanbari - Also answer was edited, I hope this help.